# Using 'or' causes the wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to make a hangman game, using 'or' in a while loop to check the input of the user. Without the 'or' the loop works fine, but when I add or with another condition, the output is always false.

```
def Guess():
guess = input("Type 'guess' to guess a character or 'answer' to guess the answer:\n>")
while guess != 'guess':
    guess = input("That is an invalid input. Please type 'guess' to guess a character or 'answer' to guess the answer:\n>")
```

This code works normally - if I input 'guess', the loop ends.

```
def Guess():
guess = input("Type 'guess' to guess a character or 'answer' to guess the answer:\n>")
while guess != 'guess' or guess != 'answer':
    guess = input("That is an invalid input. Please type 'guess' to guess a character or 'answer' to guess the answer:\n>")
```

When I add this, no matter what  I input the loop will always keep running. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guess` is always unequal to at least one of these values, so you need `and`, not `or`:

```
while guess != 'guess' and guess != 'answer':
```

If you think that's confusing or hard to read, using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you can rewrite it as:

```
while not (guess == 'guess' or guess == 'answer'):
```

A shorter and more readable solution is to use `not in`:

```
while guess not in ['guess', 'answer']:
```